# Meaning of "insufficient resources" in Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, bluetooth, core-bluetooth

Somewhat frequently, when setting a notification on a characteristic (`setNotifyValue:forCharacteristic:`), I receive the error `CBATTErrorInsufficientResources` (Code=17, "Resources are insufficient"). The only documentation for this code is "Resources are insufficient to complete the ATT request." It is not clear *what* resources are insufficient, and whether this error refers to the phone or the peripheral. At around the same time, I am writing characteristics (`writeValue:forCharacteristic:type`), and those are successful, just setting the notification is failing.

What does `CBATTErrorInsufficientResources` mean in this case?

Comment: Did you ever figure out this mystery? I'm getting the same error code, and we seem to be the only two people on the internet.

Comment: @Chriszuma This is definitely generated by the device. We issue it all over the place in our firmware for various errors. However, I was never able to figure out the cause of this particular error. It is possible I was double-subscribing to the same characteristic (slightly likely), or subscribing to a non-existant characteristic (very unlikely).

Comment: Thanks Rob, I actually figured it out, it was being generated by our Bluetooth device firmware. It was for a failure in the overly complex handshaking scheme, the original author of which having left the company